# .find is not a function in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After searching [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999944/typeerror-cannot-read-property-find-of-undefined-with-mongoose) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697448/mongodb-mongoose-insert-is-not-a-function) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557696/mongoose-this-model-is-not-a-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070473/find-is-not-a-function-mongoose-nodejs-express) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241970/mongoose-model-find-is-not-a-function) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338479/user-find-is-not-a-function-in-mongoose-model-in-nodejs) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384956/typeerror-find-is-not-a-function-nodejs-mongoose) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091707/model-find-is-not-a-function-error-when-using-mongoose-node-and-express), I still couldn't get this to work.

Basically, I have these files:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const customerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("customer", customerSchema);
```

*(customerModel.js in models/)*

and

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const customerModel = require("../../models/customerModel");

router.route("/:name").get(function(req, res) {
  const customer = new customerModel();

  customer.find({}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

*(index.js in controllers/customer/)*

When I try to access this route, it yells at me that:

```
TypeError: customer.find is not a function
```

This setup works with another file which has the same structure, but uses `.save`.

As someone pointed out on another answer:

> [...] you need to run a model and then use find on it.

which I'm already doing. I exported the model and I'm trying to use it in the other file, which doesn't work.

If someone could point out why this isn't working, I would be very glad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `customer` is an "instance" and `customerModel.find()` is what you really want. Same mistake posted many times before.

Comment: @NeilLunn It worked, you're right. I was struggling on this for one whole day now. Thank you very much. One question though: When do I need to create an instance and when not? `save` did need a instance, but `find` not, why?

Comment: I suggest taking a "day off" from "coding your application" and spend a day working through the [examples in the documentation first](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guides.html). Once you understand the examples then you can start writing other code. These things are basically covered in the first few sections of the guide

Comment: @NeilLunn I will do that. Thank you for your time. I you want to post this as a answer, I think it would help many people (that it doesn't need a instance).

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Yes, analyzing that question the cause is basically the same, but I didn't found it while searching, because find =/= update... But thanks.

Comment: Yes because the keywords doesn't match for your question but the mistake is same. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet If I mark it as a duplicate, will readers still find this particular question?

Comment: ***If I mark it as a duplicate, will readers still find this particular question?*** Yes but you cannot mark it as duplicate until you don't have `"javascript, node, mongodb, mongoose"`.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It's asking me and when clicking says: "This will mark your question as a duplicate, directing future readers to the original question and preventing further answers from being posted here."

Comment: Ok then you can go for it